# Populate 3 Elements with the same ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I saw this sample of a dropdown menu that auto populates with data supplied by mysql 
http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/phpintegration/bind-jquery-dropdownlist-to-mysql-database-using-php.htm

however what I want to do is to have 3 dropdowns supplied by different mysql tables, is it possible to do this with just one ajax call and to supply it with different parameters, or is it better to do one biggle query and save the data from all the tables in one json doc?

help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

```
$.ajax({
....
success: function(data) {
   json = JSON.parse(data);
   // then output them to the different ul's or 
   // ol's your using for your dropdown
```

Comment: so it would be better to save 3 queries in one json and then separate it by divs?

Comment: Yeah one http request > 3 http requests